# Ignore CSS on html element

Tags: html, css

I am working on a mobile site which is linked to online css which I cannot change. I added twitter bootstrap to that site. Bootstrap is applying but not 100% on all FORM HTML tags like `select`. All I want that  if styling is not applying i'll force it somehow on that element, kindly let me know how can i do that. On form tag `select` the down arrow is not comming which is quite irritating. Kindly let me know how can I force the select to behave like the by default random styling.

[image: No Down Arrow]

Comment: there is no "undo" in css. you can only add on extra css rules to try and restore overridden settings.

Comment: maybe posting the css rule and html markup can help (better if in a fiddle)

Comment: @MarcB only kindly let me know how i force the `select` tag to behave like the by default rule so that down arrow appears on it. check the image i added

Comment: what do you mean "Bootstrap is applying but not 100% on all FORM HTML", which version of bootstrap are you using? what other css files are you including? can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or link us to your site?

Comment: @Mangiucugna If you want to suggest [fiddles](http://jsfiddle.net/), that's great but please link to the site so new users can find it easily.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to put your own stylesheet embedded into the  of your document. Maybe use !important if it doesn't overwrite